# Counting text box left character length in APT.NET and jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a multi-line textbox in ASP.Net application which looks like this:

```
 <asp:TextBox 
   ID="NeedDescriptionText"
   runat="server" 
   TextMode="multiline" 
   Rows="5"
   Width="78%" 
   MaxLength="500" 
   ValidationGroup="DescriptionText">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

and a span to display the result of left character as:

```
<span id="NeedDescriptionLimit"></span><span> Character left</span>
```

Now I have jQuery code which is working perfectly on this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/snpeX/69/) as it is like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Text Box limit count.
        var origCnt = 8;
        alert("This is a test");
        $('#NeedDescriptionLimit').html(origCnt);

        $('#NeedDescriptionText').keyup(function (e) {
            var currentlen = $('#NeedDescriptionText').val().length;
            if (currentlen <= origCnt) {
                $('#NeedDescriptionLimit').html(origCnt - currentlen);
            } else {
                $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, origCnt));
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

but it is not functioning on ASP.NET app. I put the `alert()` in the code to test if jQuery is working which it was and I am getting the alert on opening the page but the character counting not working at all.

Why is this happening?

Comment: add ClientIDMode="static" to your textbox

Comment: Wow! that was quick! thanks Juan C!

Comment: Can you please just let me know what does the ClientIDMode="static" do? which without it the code was not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option:

add ClientIDMode="static" to the textbox

or replace this:

```
$('#NeedDescriptionText')
```

with this

```
$("<%= NeedDescriptionText.ClientID %>")
```

[ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).